# Parsing a json string within pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a field called financials that contains a json string.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57506d74c469888f0d631be6"),
"financials" : "{"year":[2015], ...}"
}
```

What I currently do is extract the data, convert it to a pandas dataframe, parse the string using json.loads and fiddle with the financial data from there.

Is there any way to parse the json string in pymongo, preferably as part of the aggregate pipeline as I wish to use some functions (namely `$unwind`) within pymongo?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to do it via pymongo (which could probably mean that there is no option to do it via pymongo, for example $convert operator does not have option of parsing string to json), but different solution could be via mongo shell with using JSON.parse.

> db.YourCollection.find().forEach( function(Object)
>   {var modified_data = JSON.parse(Object.financials);db.YourCollection.updateOne({_id:Object._id},{$set:{financials:modified_data}})} )